# Angular, Multiple router-outlets in multipe components

Tags: angular, routes, components, angular2-routing

I'm still learning Angular and I have trouble with my router-outlets. I have my root component (app), which has a router-outlet, this router-outlet loads my LoggedInComponent (so if you are authorised you can see all the components). Inside LoggedInComponent I have loaded my MenuComponent, inside the MenuComponent I have another router-outlet. My problem here is that I can't load other components (like dashboard) in my MenuComponent. How do I do this? Do I need auxiliary routers and how do I sure them, since this is a component, in a component, in a component?

I do get this error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard'

```
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: LoggedInComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardViewComponent, outlet:'menu'},
  { path: 'meldingen', component: MeldingenViewComponent},
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

This is the last part of code from my MenuComponent where I do have the router-outlet.

```
<div>
        <md-nav-list *ngFor="let standard of menu_standard | orderBy: 'name'">
          <a md-list-item href="{{standard.url}}">
            <i class="material-icons spacer">{{standard.icon}}</i>
            {{standard.name}}
          </a>
        </md-nav-list>
      </div>
    </md-sidenav>

  <router-outlet name="menu"></router-outlet>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: If you want a layered approach (components within components) then you want child routes, *not* aux/secondary routes. It may be difficult to figure out your specific issue/error without much more information. Can you build a Plunker to demonstrate?

Comment: And if you are interesting in diving deeper into routing, I have a course here: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-routing/table-of-contents

Comment: @DeborahK thank you! I will check out the course. I can't share my code however since I work for a company which has a non-sharing policy. So I can only share generic code.

Comment: I have reproduce the problem in stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing222-gyofle?embed=1&file=src/app/main/main.routing.module.ts